# Dropzone - auto remove thumbnail of non acceptedFiles

Tags: javascript, jquery, dropzone.js

I have applied following settings:

```
acceptedFiles: "image/jpeg, image/jpg, image/png, image/gif",
```

It is not excepting other files but thumbnail is not removed automatically, I would like to remove thumbnail too.

Currently, dropzone gives following error for non acceptedFiles: `You can't upload files of this type.`

I dont want to display that message and simply remove that thumbnail from drop area.

Can anyone let me know, how can I achieve the same?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
          init: function() {
                this.on("addedfile", function (file) {
                    var _this = this;
                    if ($.inArray(file.type, ['image/jpeg', 'image/jpg', 'image/png', 'image/gif']) == -1) {
                        _this.removeFile(file);
                    }
                });
            }
```